# macro and undeclared variables usage

Tags: assembly, macros, x86

Okay When I was making macros I couldn't get the loop to work proper if I did.

```
    move macro x,y
          mov   esi, 0 
          mov   ecx, SIZEOF x       
          a:
          mov   al, x[esi]
          mov   y[esi], al
          inc   esi
          LOOP a
endm
```

But when I add a parameter and change the label it works fine

```
move macro x,y,a
          mov   esi, 0 
          mov   ecx, SIZEOF x       
          a:
          mov   al, x[esi]
          mov   y[esi], al
          inc   esi
          LOOP a
endm
```

When I call the macro I do something along the line of 
move a,b,L1
move c,d,L2

But I'm not sure why its working..

Comment: What does 'couldn't get the loop to work proper' mean?

Comment: when I run it with the first macro it gave me error sayinga re declaring a everytime I call the macro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't parameterize the label, you'll put the *same* label in every instance where you use the macro.  You can't have the same label name at more than one place.  Your solution looks reasonable, but your assembler might also support local labels (`@@:` in some, numbered like `1:` in others), which would also solve your problem and in an easier-to-use way.